# Mostrar En selected el texto Seleccione una opcion

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Muy buenas e intentado poner en un control selected la opcion "Selecione una opcion" pero no me resulta ,el combo se esta cargando con datos de la base de datos, estoy usando el framework codeigniter,desearia que alguien me oriente en ello para poder cargar

Aqui el codigo

**usuarios_model.php**

```
    public function get_categorias(){
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COD_MODA,NOM_MODA FROM cmi_moda');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        foreach($query->result() as $row){

   $datos[($row->COD_MODA)] = $row->NOM_MODA;


}
        $query->free_result();//libera la memoria despues de usar el foreach cuando se tiene bastante data
        return $datos;



}
```

Parte de la vista  donde esta el selected views/frontend

**Usuarios.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1">Modalidad:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="Categorias" class="form-control">
                    <?php

                    foreach ($datos as $i => $categoria){

                       echo '<option values="',$i,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
                     }
                        echo print_r($datos);
                        echo var_dump($datos);

                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
```

**Controlador usuarios.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Usuarios extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Usuarios_model');
    }



    public function index()
    {
  // $this->load->view('frontend/usuarios');
// obtenemos el array de profesiones y lo preparamos para enviar
$datos['datos'] = $this->Usuarios_model->get_categorias();

// cargamos  la interfaz y le enviamos los datos
$this->load->view('frontend/usuarios',$datos);
    }
```

Quisiera lograr esto opcion Elija una opcion que se muestre la opcion [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la vista coloca el option antes del ciclo y marcalo como seleccionado, ademas puedes ponerlo como disabled ya que ese valor no esta en la base de datos:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-1">Modalidad:</label>
<div class="col-md-2">
<select name="Categorias" class="form-control">
  <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Elija una Opcion</option>
  <?php
  foreach ($datos as $i => $categoria){

    echo '<option values="',$i,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
  }

  ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-1">Modalidad:</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <select name="Categorias" class="form-control">
                    **<option value="">Elija una Opcion</option>**
                <?php

            foreach ($datos as $i => $categoria){

               echo '<option values="',$i,'">',$categoria,'</option>';
             }
                echo print_r($datos);
                echo var_dump($datos);

            ?>
            </select>
            </div>
```